# laravel 5.2 Auth:attemp always returns false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am facing issue where the auth:attempt method always returning me false value.

My Db entries are:

- username: admin
- password:
  $2y$10$jXkNy3WC2wqu0jmaqOfDiOgDnBV89uyvJPcNSU8xOnmO3w9RjT53S

Note: I stored the password manually after echoing output of Hash::make('admin').

The Code for authentication is:

```
// create our user data for the authentication
$userdata = array(
    'username'     => Input::get('username'),
    'password'  => Input::get('password'),
    'agencyactive'  => 1
);

if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) 
{
    echo 'SUCCESS!';exit;
} 
else 
{
    echo "<br>Login error";exit;
}
```

It always prints "Login Error".

For troubleshooting I logged the SQL query, it retrieves proper record,

```
select * from `agencies` where `username` = 'admin' and `agencyactive` = 1 limit 1
```

Surprisingly, when I verified the comparison as below, it prints MATCHES

```
if (\Hash::check('admin', '$2y$10$jXkNy3WC2wqu0jmaqOfDiOgDnBV89uyvJPcNSU8xOnmO3w9RjT53S'))
{
    // The passwords match...
    echo "MATCHES";
}
else
{
    echo "NO Match";
}
```

I have no clue what's going wrong here ???

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another model instead default User.

If so you can go to config/auth.php and change:

```
'model' => 'MyApp\Models\Agency',
```

for example

Comment: Yes, my Auth Settings are:
`'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
            'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Agency::class,
        ],

    ],`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

I found that, since I am using 'agencies' table (and not users), the model Agency needs to implement certain methods like

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}
```